# Increasing Ant Media System Disc Size

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

How to increase Ant Media System Disc Size via external or extra hard drives Running on Ubuntu 18.4 Server Edition?

Not done anthing other than mounting an external hard drive to my home server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should mount the hard drive to the streams directory in order to increase the disk space if it is an on-premise server.

Here are some instructions about creating a [symbolic link](https://antmedia.io/docs/guides/recording-live-streams/#storing-recordings-to-another-directory)

For cloud instances, it can be done by changing the instance type to a higher specification.